# Where do writes to stdout go when launched from a cygwin shell, no redirection

Tags: cygwin, stdout

I have an application, let's call it myapp.exe, which is dual-mode console/GUI, built as /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS (There's a tiny 3KB shim myapp.com to cause cmd.exe to wait to display the new prompt.)

If I launch from a command prompt:

- `myapp` -> cmd.exe runs myapp.com which runs myapp.exe.  stdout is initially a detached console, by using `AttachConsole` and `freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout)` my output appears in the command box.  OK
- `myapp.exe` -> cmd.exe displays the prompt too early (known problem), otherwise same as previous.  Not a normal usage scenario.
- `myapp > log` -> stdout is a file, normal use of `std::cout` ends up in the file.  OK

If I launch from Windows explorer:

- `myapp.com` -> console is created, stdout is console, output goes into console.  Same result as using /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE for the entire program, except that I've added a pause when `myapp.com` is the only process in the console.  Not a normal usage scenario.
- `myapp.exe` -> stdout is a NULL handle, I detect this and hook `std::cout` to a GUI.  OK

If I launch from Matlab shell:

- `system('myapp')` or `system('myapp.com')` or `system('myapp.exe')` -> For all three variations, stdout is piped to MatLab.  OK

If I launch from a cygwin bash shell:

- `./myapp.com` -> Just like launch from cmd.exe, the output appears in the command box.  OK
- `./myapp` -> (bash finds `./myapp.exe`).  **This is the broken case**.  stdout is a non-NULL handle but output goes nowhere.  This is the normal situation for running the program from bash and needs to be fixed!
- `./myapp > log` -> Just like launch from cmd.exe with file redirection.  OK
- `./myapp | cat` -> Similar to file redirection, except output ends up on the console window.  OK

Does anybody know what cygwin sets as stdout when launching a /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS process and how I can bind `std::cout` to it?  Or at least tell me how to find out what kind of handle I'm getting back from `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`?

My program is written with Visual C++ 2010, without `/clr`, in case that matters in any way.  OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

EDIT: Additional information requested.

CYGWIN environment variable is empty (or non-existent).

`GetFileType()` returns `FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN`.  `GetLastError()` returns `6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)`.  It doesn't matter whether I check before or after calling `AttachConsole()`.

However, if I simply ignore the invalid handle and `freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout)` then everything works great.  I was just missing a way to distinguish between (busted) console output and file redirection, and `GetFileType()` provided that.

EDIT: Final code:

```
bool is_console(HANDLE h)
{
    if (!h) return false;

    ::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);

    if (FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN == ::GetFileType(h) && ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE == GetLastError()) {
        /* workaround cygwin brokenness */
        h = ::CreateFile(_T("CONOUT$"), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
        if (h) {
            ::CloseHandle(h);
            return true;
        }
    }

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO cfi;
    return ::GetCurrentConsoleFont(h, FALSE, &cfi) != 0;
}


bool init( void )
{
    HANDLE out = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (out) {
        /* stdout exists, might be console, file, or pipe */
        if (is_console(out)) {
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
            freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
#pragma warning(pop)
        }
        //std::stringstream msg;
        //DWORD result = ::GetFileType(out);
        //DWORD lasterror = ::GetLastError();
        //msg << result << std::ends;
        //::MessageBoxA(NULL, msg.str().c_str(), "GetFileType", MB_OK);
        //if (result == FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
        //  msg.str(std::string());
        //  msg << lasterror << std::ends;
        //  ::MessageBoxA(NULL, msg.str().c_str(), "GetLastError", MB_OK);
        //}
        return true;
    }
    else {
        /* no text-mode stdout, launch GUI (actual code removed) */
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that with the default Cygwin console (started via the "Cygwin Bash Shell" shortcut)? Have you got anything in the CYGWIN environment variable, in particular `tty`? `GetFileType()` can tell you what sort of handle you're dealing with.

Comment: @ak2: `GetFileType` was just the ticket.  If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I had similar behaviour using cygwin in Console2, but it was fine using the "Cygwin64 Terminal" shortcut. Console2 had its shell set to `C:\cygwin64\bin\zsh.exe --login -i -c "cd ~;exec /bin/zsh"`

Comment: Using AttachConsole(-1) instead of AttachConsole(windowProcessId) fixed it for me, but my situation was slightly different and in C#

Comment: @JamesEJ: Where do you see `windowProcessId` anywhere in my code?  I used the symbolic constant `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS` which is an enumerated flag equal to `(unsigned)-1`, not a process ID.

Comment: That was in my code which had used GetWindowThreadProcessId from C#. My entire is_console function ended up being just the return value of AttachConsole(-1). But this may have been a very different situation just with similar symptoms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GetFileType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364960.aspx) function allows to distinguish between some types of handles, in particular consoles, pipes, files, and broken handles.